# Overloading member methods with typedef aliases as parameters

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading

I’m having some trouble overloading methods in C++.

```
typedef char int8_t;
class SomeClass{
public:
…
void Method(int8_t paramater);
void Method(char paramater);
};
```

Since `int8_t` is typedef as `char` they are just aliases, they may refer to the same type in which case overloading won’t work.

I want to make them work at the same time? Can you suggest solution to the same.
Note: I do not want to add templated method.

Following is the error:

> Error: Multiple declaration for SomeClass::Method(char)

Comment: How is the compiler going to distinguish between the two if they're both the exact same signature to the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might gain some degree of improvement by trying this:

```
void Method(char paramater);
void Method(signed char paramater);
void Method(unsigned char paramater);
```

If an implementation defines `int8_t`, and if the definition matches one of those three, then the correct function will get called.

However, a devious implementation could do something like this:

```
typedef __special_secret_sauce int8_t;
```

and then you would need to define another overload for `int8_t`.  It's pretty tough for you to define another overload for `int8_t` to contend with those implementations and at the same time not define it for implementations that typedef `int8_t` as `signed char`.  Someone else said it's not even possible.

There can be implementations where `int8_t` doesn't exist at all.  If you just define overloads for the three variations of char then you'll have no problem there.

Answer (score 5):

Use a faux type. Wrap one of `char` or `int8_t` in a structure and use the structure as a parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, since i am using this typedef from solaris platforms int_types.h

Comment: You can use something like: `struct faux_int8_t{ int8_t x;};`

Comment: Since I am using typedef from solaris platforms int_types.h I cannot use above struct that you mentioned.

Comment: @user1393608 then do `typedef struct {char x;} faux_char;`. Unless your specific platform doesn't support structs, this will work just fine in both C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

> ... they may refer to the same type in which case overloading won’t
>   work. I want to make them work at the same time?

Fortunately that's not possible (even with `templates`). Because it kills the very purpose of a `typedef`.
If you intend to do this in your code then it's a *code smell*; you may have to change your design.